# How to retain the background color of clicked cards even on refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am having a 6 bootstrap cards as a step in a form wizard and I am having a next button which goes to the next page and then come back the clicked cards are retaining its background color so, my problem when I come back click another card other than that of previously clicked cards and again click next and come back the recently clicked cards only retaining its color For example the first time If I click the 1 and 2 cards and click next and again come back my 1 and 2 are retaining its color and when I again click the 3 and 4 cards and click next again and come back the 3 and 4 cards are retaining its color, not the 1 and 2 but I need all the four cards to retain their color 
My HTML code is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // goals

  $("#room_1").click(function() {
    $("#room_1").toggleClass("blue")
  });

  $("#room_2").click(function() {
    $("#room_2").toggleClass("blue")
  });

  $("#room_3").click(function() {
    $("#room_3").toggleClass("blue")
  });

  $("#room_4").click(function() {
    $("#room_4").toggleClass("blue")
  });

  $("#room_5").click(function() {
    $("#room_5").toggleClass("blue")
  });

  $("#room_6").click(function() {
    $("#room_6").toggleClass("blue")
  });

  $("#room_7").click(function() {
    $("#room_7").toggleClass("blue")
  });

  $("#room_8").click(function() {
    $("#room_8").toggleClass("blue")
  });

  $("#room_9").click(function() {
    $("#room_9").toggleClass("blue")

  });

});
var goal = []
var goalIds = [];

function getGoal(id) {
  if (goal.length > 0) {
    var data = {
      id: id,
      content: $("#cont_" + id).text()
    }
    var x = JSON.stringify(data)
    var index = goal.indexOf(x)
    if (index == -1) {
      goal.push(x)
    } else {
      goal.splice(index, 1)
    }
  } else {
    var data = {
      id: id,
      content: $("#cont_" + id).text()
    }
    var x = JSON.stringify(data)
    goal.push(x)
  }
  localStorage.setItem("goal", JSON.stringify(goal))
  goalIds = goal.map(element => JSON.parse(element).id);
  console.log(goalIds)
  issample();
}

function issample() {
  $("#goal").val(goalIds);
  console.log(goalIds)
}

function initGoals() {
  var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("goal") || '[]');
  goalIds = storedNames.map(element => JSON.parse(element).id);
}
$(function() {
  let storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("goal") || '[]');
  $.each(storedNames, function(index, value) {
    let temp = JSON.parse(value);
    $('#room_' + temp['id']).addClass("blue");
    console.log($('#' + temp['id']).attr('id'));
  });
})
```

```css
/* navbar*/
.navbar{
 height:80px;
}

/*container0*/
.container0{
  height:550px;
}

/*container*/
.container1{
 background-color:white ;
 width:450px;
}

/*navbar-brand*/
.navbar-brand{
  font-family: 'Monda', sans-serif;
}

/*container-fluid*/
.container-fluid{
  background-color: blue;
  height:1000px;
}

/*button1*/
.btn1{
 background-color: #000080;
 border: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 15px 32px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 16px;
 margin: 4px 2px;
 cursor: pointer;
 }

 /*button2*/
 .btn2 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black; 
  border: 2px solid #000080;
  width:180px;
}
.btn2:hover {
  background-color: #000080;
  color:white;
}

/*container-3*/
.container-3{
  display:inline-block;
  width:600px;
  height:500px;
  
}
.link{
  { color: black; }
}

/*card-6*/
.card6{
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 40%;
}
.card6:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/*card-4*/
.card4{
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 40%;
}
.card4:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/*Button4*/
.btn4{
  width:300px;
  background-color: white;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/*previous button*/
.previous {
  background-color:white;
  color: black;
  width:300px;
  display:block;
  border: 2px solid #000080;
}

/*next button*/
.next {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  width:300px;
  display:block;
  border: 2px solid #000080;
}

/* round class*/
.round {
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/*.btn card*/
.btncard{
  background-color: #000080;
}

/*.blue class*/
.blue{
border: 2px solid #000080;
}
/*range slider*/
input[type="range"]{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-apperance: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 600px;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    right top,
    color-stop(0.15,  #C5C5C5),
    color-stop(0.15, #C5C5C5)
    );
  }

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    border-radius: 50%; 
    background-color: #E9E9E9;
    border: 3px solid #CECECE;
    height: 25px;
    width: 15px;
}

/*container-11*/
.container-11{
  width:600px;
  background-color: white;
  height:800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

/*container1*/
.con1{
  width:800px;
  height:400px;
  border:1px solid grey;
}

/*register*/
#register{
  background-color:  #000080;
}

/*messages*/
.messages{
  color:orange;
}
.messages h5{
  font-style: italic;
}
#name_error{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-4" onclick="getGoal(1)">
    <div class="card4 mt-3" id="room_1" style="width: 12rem; height:9rem;">
      <center>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text mt-4" id="cont_1"><b>I am redecorating</b></p>
        </div>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-4" onclick="getGoal(2)">
    <div class="card4 mt-3" id="room_2" style="width: 12rem; height:9rem;">
      <center>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text mt-4" id="cont_2"><b>I am Moving</b></p>
        </div>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-4" onclick="getGoal(3)">
    <div class="card4 mt-3" id="room_3" style="width: 12rem; height:9rem;">
      <center>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text mt-4" id="cont_3"><b>I need help with a layout</b></p>
        </div>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-4" onclick="getGoal(4)">
    <div class="card4 mt-3" id="room_4" style="width: 12rem; height:9rem;">
      <center>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text mt-4" id="cont_4"><b>I am looking for a species</b></p>
        </div>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-4" onclick="getGoal(5)">
    <div class="card4 mt-3" id="room_5" style="width: 12rem; height:9rem;">
      <center>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text mt-4" id="cont_5"><b>I am moving with someone</b></p>
        </div>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-4" onclick="getGoal(6)">
    <div class="card4 mt-3" id="room_6" style="width: 12rem; height:9rem;">
      <center>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text mt-4" id="cont_6"><b>Other</b></p>
        </div>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<!--Loop ends-->
<a class="link mt-3"><u>Dont see your room?</u></a>
</p>
<div class="row mb-3">
  <div class="col-4 mr-5">
    <a href="/modsy/rooms/" class="previous" onClick="history.go(-1);">&laquo; Home</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 ml-5">
    <a href="/modsy/furniture" class="next">Next &raquo;</a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Codepen code ishttps://codepen.io/lakshmi123__/pen/xxbzwNP

Comment: in your local storage, one set of 2 values is saving. even you click all it will remember only 2.

Comment: so for that what should I do now can you say to save all four

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the Code Snippet

[How to retain the background color of clicked cards even on refresh?](https://codepen.io/arvindmaurya37/pen/RwNJZNE)

```
function getGoal(id) {
    debugger;
    var goalsArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("goal"));
    var b = goalsArray.filter(function (x) {
        debugger;
        return x.id == id;
    });
    if (goalsArray != null) {
        var data = {
            id: id,
            content: $("#cont_" + id).text()
        }
        if (b.length >= 1) {
            //then delete
            var filtredArray = goalsArray.filter(function (x) {
                return x.id != b[0].id;
            })
            goalsArray = filtredArray;
        }
        else {
            //add
            goalsArray.push(data);
        }
    }
    localStorage.setItem("goal", JSON.stringify(goalsArray))
    issample();
}
```

If you code of getGoal local storage was getting reset.
like on-page refresh sometime old values where getting deleted.
just have a look at code getGoal function above.

Answer (score 0):

I preferred you to create a array that hold all ids that have checked and store in cookie. and once you come back to this page again use this array to get all ids for select.

For set and get data from cookies use this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

Comment: But I had used local storage already for that can you say please

Comment: then use that storage for save array and select value from that storage.

Comment: yes every time when I go back the local storage is getting freshly the clicked ones

Comment: can you please explain which type of local storage you use ?

Comment: var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("goal") || '[]');

Comment: this is what I wrote to get the clicked ones details into the storedNames